# Shade Smooth and Auto-Smooth problem when combining objects

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, normals

So I'm making a catapult and I need all the parts of the arm joined together so when I animate it, they all move together.

[image: Image of the front of the arm modelled]

The problem is when I join up the parts of the basket and arms in the front together, the shading gets messed up because the arms are shaded smooth with auto-smoothing and the chain link has been shaded smooth without auto-smoothing isn't. Refer to images below.

[image: The chain link sin't auto smoothed because it looks fine with just shade smooth]

How do I make it so that both the chain and the arms retain their individual smoothing settings or combine them in such a way that both look good?

[image: When I join up the parts, the arms stay nice and shaded but the chain becomes sharp again]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 01**
Smooth/flat shading is applied *per face*, not per object.
So just change it for individual faces of your mesh.

Here is an example of a chain.
It's one object, consisting of multiple meshes, like in your case.

Select only one mesh.
Click a face and then *Select->Select Linked->Linked*
[image]

Apply shading only to these faces.
*Mesh->Shading->Smooth faces*
[image]

You're done.
Different parts of your object are now shaded differently.
[image]

**Solution 02**
Play with the Auto-smooth angle.
Auto-smooth is applied per the whole object, but you can adjust what edges are considered smooth.
[image]

**Solution 02.1**
(thanks to [Robin Betts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/35559/robin-betts))
Mark some edges as sharp.
They will then be shaded flat, no matter what the angle is.
*Edge->Mark Sharp.*
[image]

Comment: Also, smoothing groups can be separated by marking the edges between them 'Sharp'

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll add it to my answer so it's all in one place :).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I finally got it to work!

Answer (score 1):

Select the object you want to preserve smoothing and click [**add custom split normal data**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/custom_data.html) at the mesh properties geometry data section. This will properly mark your edges sharp. You can then join your objects. Make sure the newly joint object has auto-smooth enabled.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How to combine a Shade Smooth and an Auto-Smooth object together in Blender? Jachym's answer is great, but I would like to add a few additional notes I discovered today:

The result of Auto-Smooth shading will look **different** than if you simply select certain faces and set Shade Smooth or Shade Flat (via the Object Context Menu, accessible via "W" key for Right-Click Users, or by right-clicking for Left-Click Users).

If that's the look you want, then great. However, if you want to exactly match the shading achieved with Auto-Smooth, you will need to use an **Edge-Split Modifier** (either with the "Edge Angle" setting, which is identical to Auto-Smooth behavior, or with the "Sharp Edges" setting, where you manually choose what edges will be sharp by pressing *Ctrl E > Mark Sharp* or *Edge > Mark Sharp* on selected Edges in Edit-Mode).

The differences in Shading can be clearly seen in the 3 example images below:

**1.** Faces set to "Shade Smooth", "Auto Smooth" Enabled:
[image: Shade Smooth+Auto Smooth_Blender]

**2.** Faces set to both Shade Smooth and Shade Flat, "Auto Smooth" Disabled.

**Note how the reflection on the inner rim has CHANGED:**

[image: Shade Smooth+Shade Flat_Auto Smooth OFF_Blender]

**3.** Faces set to "Shade Smooth", Edges Marked as "Sharp", and EdgeSplit Modifier.

**Note how the reflection in the inner rim matches the Auto-Smooth version EXACTLY:**

[image: Shade Smooth+Edges Marked Sharp+EdgeSplit Modifier_Blender]

If you use the Edge Split Modifier version, be sure to APPLY the modifier before joining this object to a different object that uses Smooth Shading on all its faces. *You can apply any modifier by hovering over it an pressing Ctrl A.*